# Foundation 4 Orbit Custom Transition

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, easing, orbit

I'm trying to customize the transition of the Foundation 4 Orbit component. I want to change the ease property but I've can't do it.

In the [docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html) says: use the property `orbit_transition_class` to specify my own class which is as follow:

```
.my-transition {
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

This is my Hmarkup:

```
<ul data-orbit data-options="orbit_transition_class:my-transition;">
```

I don't know what I doing wrong, Can somebody tell me how to achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation says:

> Orbit options can only be passed in during initialization at this
>   time.

You need to initialize orbit (and any of Foundation's component for that matter) like this:

```
$(document).foundation('orbit', {
    orbit_transition_class: 'my-transition'
});
$(document).foundation();
```

Comment: In the official documentation says:
--- Starting in 4.0.7 you can also use the data-options attribute to pass configuration settings to Orbit. Treat it like a style property. --- I'm asking how to set the transition value to the `orbit_transition_class` property.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, so I looked at the Orbit source code in my version of Foundation (4.3.2). It turns out the `orbit_transition_class` setting exists but is not currently being used for anything.

This is either a bug or they are still phasing out/phasing in this setting.

You can check if your version is using it by doing a text search for "orbit_transition_class" in the `js/foundation/foundation.orbit.js` file. If you only get one result, in the settings object, it is probably an unused setting.

Update: I switched to WooThemes FlexSlider 2, which seems to be more flexible.